# Which element should I be using for a mixed menu of controls and links?

Tags: html, mobile, semantic-markup

I just learned about `<menu>` vs. `<nav>` but am somewhat confused as to which I should use when the items include both links and control actions (eg. Website, Email, Call).

Comment: Could you give an example of your content? What kind of controls? -- And why did you use the [tag:mobile] tag?

Comment: Did my answer helped you out? If it's not quite the type of answer you were looking for, give us a preview of your content; I would edit my answer to better suit your need! :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3C

```
<nav>
```

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other
>   pages or to parts within the page: **a section with navigation links**.

```
<menu>
```

> Although previous versions of HTML defined the menu element as a
>   generic “single column menu list”, the element has now been given the
>   very specific purpose of representing a list of commands.

**Conclusion**

`<menu>`'s purpose is to group a list of command such as toolbars or contextual menu while `<nav>` is meant for links to navigate through content (most likely from one page to another).

Hope this helps!